# jupyter notebook save error with ascii codec error message

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i have problem with jupyter notebook file saving system.

[image: error message]

Does anyone here who got the same message?
I'm using python 2.7 in linux Centos server. There is no error with code but if there are hanguel like '한글' in input or output cell, the error message comes out automatically(auto saving problem).

Comment: Read about ascii values and it's range of values, you will get to know.

Comment: You might want to encode your string, this question is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: I am getting the same error, and it is related to having a rendered plot in my notebook.  I make my plots with matplotlib; it is setup with these commands:%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   . I can avoid this error message by clearing the output cells prior to saving

Comment: In my case, where the problem was seemingly caused by non-ascii characters in a matplotlib plot, it was solved by (finally!) update from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7

Comment: @Vincent Marchetti Thanks! unfortunately i cannot update python.. I'm using centos now, the problem comes from centos's language package. maybe. anyway thanks!

Comment: I got the same error but it went away after I cleared the output of a `pip install python-docx`. Hope that helps someone who runs into a similar error.